# Configuration of a Red5 server

Tags: flash, red5

I just made an install of red5 on a windows 7 computer. I had developed a flash application and it works very well with the my local red5 server.
I would still have access to my red5 from a remote connexion. When i try to replace the IP 127.0.0.1 in my application with the IP address of my server, it does not work.

I tried to change the port 5080 by 80 for my http protocol in "red5.properties" thinking it could be blocked by my router but this does not change. I access locally at http://localhost/ but not remotely with my IP address.

Clarification, I have a Netgear router CBVG834G.

What are the configurations to be made to access my server remotely ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How about file access permission?
try to chmod 755 your folder.